# how do I turn wordpress into a virtualhost?

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp

[image: photo of local host in wamp]

I've tried going through the Wordpress tutorial but I also don't know how to fill in the php config file this shows up:

Basically i've got everything except for php?

[image: photo of wp-admin/install.php in browser]

Answer (score 0):

Thats url is wrong, use http://localhost/wordpressFolder/

unzip wordpress righ there

```
C:\wamp64\www\
```

example final folder structure, just like your capture

```
C:\wamp64\www\wordpress
```

In the browser use

http://localhost/wordpress/

off course start apache before and you need create a database first, here 
http://localhost/phpmyadmin